# Assigning A default getway to a pc

Tags: bash

I am writing a module to assign getway to pc.I have been using "route" command for it bt the comman is not working. The codes i have used are

```
    echo type getway

    read gwn

    echo GETWAY: $gwn



    function valid_gwn()

    {

        local  gw=$1

        local  stat=1

        if [[ $gwn =~ ^[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}$ ]];
     then

            OIFS=$IFS

            IFS='.'

            gw=($gwn)

            IFS=$OIFS
            [[ ${gw[0]} -le 255 && ${gw[1]} -le 255 \
                && ${gw[2]} -le 255 && ${gw[3]} -le 255 ]]

            stat=$?

        fi

        return $stat
    }


    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]] && valid_gwn

    then

    echo good;

    else

    echo bad;

    fi



route add  default gw $gwn eth0 metric 1
```

Please clarify the mistakes that i made.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: it says the "SIOCADDRT: No such process"

Comment: Check if your eth0 interface is in UP state: sudo ifconfig -a

Comment: yes it is in UP state

Comment: I've tested your bash and it did produce the correct 'route' command, but that SIOCADDRT error can be caused by multiple reasons and depends on your network config, so you'll need to investigate the reason.

Comment: can you please tell me in detail what shoul d i look for??

Comment: there is a link below provided by @Jord, you can start there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think I will have to compile anything from my end, as there is a [good explanation given for the issue here](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH142841)

I guess, for debugging you should be echoing `$gwn` before setting the route.
Largely if nothing wrong happening while setting `$gwn` in script then this question could have been asked in Superuser of askubuntu.

Comment: The generated command is correct, but the reasons of SIOCADDRT can be different as yo noted, so it's not really a bash issue. It's a route command issue that needs to be investigated according to the link.

Comment: Missed to add it as comment, answer from me belongs as a comment.